# Найти по классам и добавить атрибут

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function add_class() {
 var p_id = $('input[name=\"product_id\"]').val();
 var p_q = "$('input[name=\"quantity\"]').val()";
 $('#button-cart').addClass(p_id).attr('onclick', 'cart.add(\''+p_id+'\', '+p_q+');');

 $('.cart .button, .btn-group .btn, .btn-group .btn-primary, .button-group button').each(function() {
  if(($(this).attr('onclick') && $(this).attr('onclick').substr(0, 9) == 'addToCart') || ($(this).attr('onclick') && $(this).attr('onclick').substr(0, 8) == 'cart.add')) {
   var p_id = $(this).attr('onclick').substr(8, 14);
   var p_class = p_id.match(/(\d+)/g);
   $(this).addClass(''+p_class);
  }
 });
}
```

По логике должен строка ниже должна находить все #button-cart и присваивать им атрибут, но этого не происходит. Просьба подсказать

```js
$('#button-cart').addClass(p_id).attr('onclick', 'cart.add(\''+p_id+'\', '+p_q+');');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `#button-cart` - это идентификатор, он должен быть уникальным, и не встречаться у нескольких элементов сразу.
Если `button-cart` сделать не id, а классом, то получится. Т.е. вместо

```
<div id="button-cart" ...
```

сделать

```
<div class="button-cart" ...
```

и вместо

```
$('#button-cart').addClass(p_id).attr('onclick',....
```

сделать

```
$('.button-cart').addClass(p_id).attr('onclick',....
```

P.s.: события лучше навешивать на элемент не через `.attr('onclick',...`, а через `.on('click', ...` или `.click(...)`.